# Scratch Org Pod Location

Tags: scratch-org, ip-whitelisting

If you specifically asked Salesforce for your production instance to be located at a particular region, e.g. AWS Sydney Region, and that is your devhub, does that mean that each scratch org is also going to be spun up on the servers within the same region?

Reason being, is whitelisting IP ranges for our middleware. I would like to make sure that it's guaranteed we won't have issues during our development lifecycle by a scratch org suddenly being created elsewhere outside the IP ranges for this particular geolocation. I don't want to whitelist all Salesforce IP ranges for every region if I don't have to.

By the looks of it, so far, all of my scratch orgs (and sandboxes) end up being in Sydney, though is there some sort of documentation or a best practice for IP whitelisting when working with scratch orgs?

Comment: I'd check what will happen to the orgs in question when the continuous site switching occurs. And to some degree a scheduled org migration. You might find your orgs moved to different IP ranges.

Comment: Docs say: `If your internet entry points are all contained within Australia AND your only Salesforce org(s) is/are on an Australia instance, then you may whitelist only Australia ARIN numbers.`. While this might be ok for Prod, it's still a question for any sandboxes / scratch orgs. I can't find anything related to that